# Code Mysteriously Stops Working

Tags: javascript, html

This code worked fine for about a week (much longer before that as well, however I've since then greatly improved the internal function).  It's not complex to read, but for some reason yesterday, it stops working.  I didn't change anything to this portion of the code and have kept this portion of the script separated into it's own script tag at the bottom of the file with all of the HTML id's staying exactly the same (this gigantic table sorta stands out in the source file so it's easy to avoid)...  Anybody else experience something like this?  If anybody see's anything obvious, let me know...

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
      function Kill_Count(id,totalDeaths) {
        var deathsPerSecond = totalDeaths/365/24/60/60/4;
        var deaths = 0, result;
        var timer = 1;
        setInterval(function() {    
          deaths = deathsPerSecond*timer;     
          result = deaths.toFixed();
          document.getElementById(id).value = result;
          timer++;
        }, 250);
      }
      
      var killnum = "23199336 1501799 301275455 49877536490 2676365000 402611664 5018470 1375940758 564785251 635382008";
      killnum = killnum.split(" ");
      for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        var num = i-1;
        var temp = killnum[num];
        Kill_Count('Kill_Count'+i,Number(temp));
      }
    });
```

```html
    <table id="Killed" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Buffalo</td>
                <td align="right">
                  <span id="Kill_Count1"></span>
                </td>
              </tr>
    
              <tr>
                <td>Camels</td>
                <td align="right">
                  <span id="Kill_Count2"></span>
                </td>
              </tr>
    
              <tr>
                <td>Cattle</td>
                <td align="right">
                  <span id="Kill_Count3"></span>
                </td>
              </tr>
    
              <tr>
                <td>Chickens</td>
                <td align="right">
                  <span id="Kill_Count4"></span>
                </td>
              </tr>
    
              <tr>
                <td>Ducks</td>
                <td align="right">
                  <span id="Kill_Count5"></span>
                </td>
              </tr>
    
              <tr>
                <td>Goats</td>
                <td align="right">
                  <span id="Kill_Count6"></span>
                </td>
              </tr>
    
              <tr>
                <td>Horses</td>
                <td align="right">
                  <span id="Kill_Count7"></span>
                </td>
              </tr>
    
              <tr>
                <td>Pigs</td>
                <td align="right">
                  <span id="Kill_Count8"></span>
                </td>
              </tr>
    
              <tr>
                <td>Sheep</td>
                <td align="right">
                  <span id="Kill_Count9"></span>
                </td>
              </tr>
    
              <tr>
                <td>Turkeys</td>
                <td align="right">
                  <span id="Kill_Count10"></span>
                </td>
              </tr>
    
            </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Try reproducing your issue here http://jsbin.com

Comment: "it stops working"  Can you be more specific? It doesn't load, render or certain functions fail?

Comment: Can you explain what you expect the code to do and what you mean by "it stops working"?

Comment: "Stopped working" is not very descriptive.  Please describe the observed behavior and the desired behavior and what errors (if any) show in the debug console.

Comment: I expect the code to update the kill count 4 times a second (like it was doing for weeks) so that it gives a real time perspective.  What I mean when it stops working is that nothing gets injected into the table, I only see the animal names from the HTML.

Why is my question getting downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to change value to innerHTML or innerText, in your setInterval function.

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML= result;
```

I'm not sure what changed to break it though.

http://jsfiddle.net/g2Lodf23/

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I didn't see that, btw, do you know the rule for innerHTML, innerText and value or is it all arbitrarily assigned?